# Статическая ссылочная переменная

Tags: java

В чем особенность статической ссылочной переменной?
Как я понял, что если мы создадём в классе ссылку с типом объекта(например, static Dog d), то при создании, допустим, объекта класса в тестовом методе и добавлении данной ссылке объекта ссылка в классе(d) будет ссылаться на объект, который мы задали. Тогда при создании последующих объектов данного класса в тестовом методе они будут иметь данную ссылку с тем объектом, который мы задали при создании предыдущего объекта в тестовом классе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Статический член класса (ссылочный или нет) принадлежит *определению класса* и не принадлежит ни одному объекту этого класса.

Статический член класса не имеет никакого отношения к "созданию" экземпляров этого класса.